# Best approximation for a normed vector space $X$

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, soft-question, approximation-theory

I am self-studying functional analysis. As far as I know, a best approximation of $X$ by a closed subspace $C \subseteq X$ exists and is unique if $X$ is a Hilbert space, a uniformly convex Banach space, or more generally, a reflexive space.

My question is: is there a even more general condition on the space $X$ for the existence and uniqueness of the best approximation of $X$ by a closed and convex subspace $C \subseteq X$?

Any comments or suggested readings are welcome.

Comment: Maybe interesting: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/778777/uniqueness-of-best-approximation-in-strictly-or-uniformly-convex-normed-linear-s, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/35449/why-isnt-the-theorem-of-approximation-applicable-in-banach-spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharper results: [Best Approximation by Closed Sets in Banach Spaces](http://www.math.cuhk.edu.hk/%7Ekslau/publication/Best%20approximations%20by%20closed%20sets%20in%20Banach%20spaces.pdf) and [On a sufficient condition for proximity](http://www.math.cuhk.edu.hk/%7Ekslau/publication/On%20a%20Sufficient%20Condition%20for%20Proximity.pdf) by [Ka Sing Lau](http://www.math.cuhk.edu.hk/%7Ekslau/).
Quote from the first:

> The set $K$ is called *proximinal* (*Chebyshev*) if every point $x\in X$ has a (unique) best approximation from $X$. lt is easy to see that every closed convex set $X$ in a reflexive space $X$ is proximinal. In addition, if the norm is strictly convex, then $X$ is Chebyshev. However, if $X$ is not assumed reflexive or $X$ is not assumed convex, then the above result is false in general. In [7] Steckin introduced the concept of almost Chebyshev. A set $K$ is called almost Chebyshev if the set of $x$ in $X$ such that $K$ fails to have unique best approximation to $x$ is a first category subset of $X$. He proved that if $X$ is a uniformly convex Banach space, then every closed subset is almost Chebyshev. By using this concept, Garkavi [4] showed that for any reflexive subspace $F$ in a separable Banach space, there exists a (in fact, many) subspace $G$ which is $B$-isomorphic to $F$ and is almost Chebyshev. The author [6] showed that if $X$ is a separable Banach space which is locally uniformly convex or possesses the Radon-Nikodym property, then "almost all"
> closed subspaces are almost Chebyshev. In [3], Edelstein proved that if $X$
> has the Radon-Nikodym property, then for any bounded cIosed convex
> subset $K$, the set of $x$ in $X$ which admit best approximations from $K$ is a
> weakly dense subset in $X$.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize Professor Lau has such a publication! Indeed he is the instructor of my undergraduate functional analysis course last year and he has just retired.

Comment: @CheungSW, ¡El mundo es un pañuelo! (This is a small world!) :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Probably this is one of the most general result we can get until now. If there were some well-known and more general results in classical texts I expect this question to be answered earlier.