# purpose of interpolants in Galerkin methods

Tags: functional-analysis, numerical-methods, finite-element-method, galerkin-methods

I am learning about the finite element method in an abstract Banach and Hilbert space setting, especially for an application to differential forms, and I am a bit lost on the *big picture* about the purpose and the necessity of quasi-interpolants.

My understanding of the abstract Galerkin setting, so far, is that we start with two infinite dimensional normed spaces $U$ and $V$ that need to be complete (to allow formulating what convergence means). Then we regard the continuous problem: given a possibly unbounded operator $L:U\to V^*$ and a piece of data $f\in V^*$ which is the continuous dual space of $V$ it displays as

$$\text{seek }u\in U\text{ such that }L\,u=f$$

This is approximated with a Galerkin method by picking finite dimensional normed subspaces $U_h\subset U$ and $V_h\subset V$. To make this suitable for *real world* methods, one allows $L_h$ to differ from the restriction $L|_{U_h}$ and $f_h$ to differ from the restriction $f|_{V_h^*}$. Therefore the discrete problem is

$$\text{seek }u_h\in U_h\text{ such that }L_h\,u_h=f_h$$

Now, *the error which we are interested in to control* is $\|u-u_h\|_{U}$ where "control" means "bounding towards zero as $h$ tends to zero".

When $U$ is an inner product space, then we can define a best approximation $u_h^{\text{best}}$ of $u$ in $U_h$ as the orthogonal projection of $u$ onto $U_h$ using this inner product. This gives the best approximation error

$$\|u-u_h^{\text{best}}\|_U=\inf_{v_h\,\in\,U_h}\|u-v_h\|_U$$

By the triangle inequality we can bound $\|u-u_h\|_{U}$ with the the error from $u$ to $u_h^{\text{best}}$ plus the error from $u_h^{\text{best}}$ to $u_h$.

$$\|u-u_h\|_{U}\le \|u-u_h^{\text{best}}\|_U+\|u_h^{\text{best}}-u_h\|_{U_h}$$

When $U$ is not an inner product space, then we can still define the best approximation error with the infimum, but (how) do we still obtain a best approximation (the element)? Something like

$$u_h^{\text{best}}=\operatorname*{arginf}_{v_h\,\in\,U_h}\|u-v_h\|_U$$

If $U_h$ *takes* the infimum (does it?), isn't it a minimium then? I could think that the ill-posedness of such a definition could be one reason to introduce an interpolator that actually obtains a value in $U_h$.

> Update: Yes, I think so. Since $U_h$ is finite dimensional and
>
> - All finite dimensional normed vector spaces are complete. [(*)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168275/proof-that-every-finite-dimensional-normed-vector-space-is-complete)
> - A complete subspace must be closed [(*)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6750/difference-between-complete-and-closed-set)
> - A closed set contains all its limit points [(*)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3099688/prove-that-a-closed-set-contains-all-its-limit-points)

But then, commonly $U$ is chosen to be the space of square integrable funtions $L^2$ over some domain and this comes with an inner product. Still people introduce quasi-interpolants $\mathcal I_h$ on complete inner product spaces. So maybe for *concrete finite element theories* (a combination of finite element spaces and a boundary value problem) it turns out to be *helpful* to have a detour over $\mathcal I_h\,u$ in the triangle inequality then?

$$\|u-u_h\|_{U}\le \|u-\mathcal I_h\,u\|_U+\|\mathcal I_h\,u-u_h\|_{U_h}$$

The next aspect is that the degrees of freedom on simplices are defined as integrals over sub-simplex traces. They just need to be unisolvent (to form a basis for the dual space) but most authors seem to use them like the resulting functionals are also a *dual basis* to the finite element basis functions. The necessity of the sub-simplex restriction is not quite clear to me. [*Hiptmair (1999) - Canonical construction of finite elements*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220576357_Canonical_construction_of_finite_elements) includes this as a locality requirement in the very definition of degrees of freedom

> For the local ansatz spaces on the reference element we adopt the notation $\mathcal X^l_k(\hat T)$, where $l$ stands for the order of the differential forms and $k\in\mathbb N_0$ is related to the degree of the polynomials.
>
> [...]
>
> Lemma 7. Let $\hat f$ denote an $(n - 1)$-dimensional "face" of the reference simplex $\hat T$. Then the trace of $\omega\in\mathcal X^l_k(\hat T)$ on $\hat f$ belongs to the space $\omega\in\mathcal X^l_k(\hat f)$.
>
> [...]
>
> 1. **Unisolvence**: ... is a basis of the dual space $\mathcal X^l_k(\hat T)'$
> 2. **Invariance**: ... remain invariant under canonical transformations of differential forms accompanying a transformation of the reference simplex.
> 3. **Locality**: For any face $\hat f$ of the simplex $\hat T$ and $\omega\in \mathcal X^l_k(\hat T)$ the trace $\omega_{|\hat f}$ is uniquely determined by certain degrees of freedom that depend only on $\omega_{|\hat f}$.

There is a *canonical* interpolant $\mathcal I_h$ being defined by directly using the degrees of freedom to map $u$ to  coefficients and then multiply these with the corresponding basis elements to obtain a function $\mathcal I_h\,u\in U_h$. Authors now complain that because some of the degrees of freedom are restricted to subsimplices, it is not possible to bound $\|u-\mathcal I_h\,u\|_{U}$ when $u$ has low regularity.

Couldn't we just use the $U$-inner product here to obtain a dual basis of $U_h$ in the case that $U$ is an inner product space such as $L^2$? I mean not for the degrees of freedom but for the interpolant. This would be equivalent to a best approximation then, I guess. There is the Clément interpolant construction which seems to do something similar by multiplying a hat function of some node with the best $u$-matching polynomial up to order $r$ over all simplices that share this node. What are the benefits of this construction over the orthogonal projection / best approximation?

**To sum up, my questions are**

1. Do we still have a best approximation (the element) when $U$ is not an inner product space?
2. What is the *high level reason* for the introduction of interpolation operators besides that everyone does it like that? (is it necessary or just *helpful* to obtain error bounds?)
3. Why don't we use the $L^2$ inner product directly to define quasi-interpolants?
4. What is the difference of an interpolant and a quasi-interpolant?

---

*Update:* after reading a bit more, I found some hints

1. *"a best approximation of X by a closed subspace $C\subseteq X$ exists and is unique if $X$ is a Hilbert space, a uniformly convex Banach space, or more generally, a reflexive space."* [(*)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1022486/best-approximation-for-a-normed-vector-space-x)
2. It seems to be a strategy to obtain global error bounds from local error bounds: *"the Lagrange interpolation operator $\mathcal I^1_h$ possesses numerous local interpolation properties. In other words, one observes that the interpolation error is controlled elementwise before it is controlled on a global level. This observation serves as a motivation for the introduction of local interpolation operators."* [(*)](https://www.wias-berlin.de/people/john/BETREUUNG/master_zepernick.pdf)
3. People use the $L^2$ projection in that manner so it might be that it does not possess some *important properties*. Commutation with the exterior derivative and with local transformations (pullbacks) and also preservation of boundary conditions might be desirable here. Still, this is just a guess.
4. It seems that the nomer *interpolation* is used in a generalized sense and does not imply the exact reproduction of function values at specific points anymore so some authors use the prefix *quasi* to account for this. *"The term “interpolation” is used here in a broad sense, since the degrees of freedom (dofs) are not necessarily point evaluations. For the interpolation operator to be useful, one needs to extend the domain of the linear forms"* [(*)](https://hal.science/hal-03226049/document)